# Hide some of the labels from venn diagram

Tags: python, pandas, venn-diagram

I plotted a venn diagram that I'd like to hide part of the labels but don't know how to.

Example data

```
Course1=['A','C','Q']
Course2=['B','E','F','H','K','Q','R','S','T','U','V','Z']
Course3=['C','E','G']
vd3=venn3([set(Course1),set(Course2),set(Course3)],
 set_labels=('Course1', 'Course2','Course3'),
 set_colors=('#c4e6ff', '#F4ACB7','#9D8189'), 
 alpha = 0.8)
venn3_circles([set(Course1), set(Course2),set(Course3)], linestyle='-.', linewidth=2, color='grey')
plt.show()
```

[image]

How to hide Course 1 blue part and Course 3 brown part labels (the number "1") as they have no intersection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `.get_label_by_id().set_text()` to set the text of spefic part.

```py
vd3.get_label_by_id('100').set_text('')
vd3.get_label_by_id('001').set_text('')
```

[image]

To know what's the id of each part, you could use the following snippet to check

```py
labels = ['100', '101', '110', '010', '001', '011', '111']
for label in labels:
    vd3.get_label_by_id(label).set_text(label)
```